# PDFBox - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jpeg (Library is already loaded in another ClassLoader)

Tags: jpeg, classloader, pdfbox, javax.imageio

I just integrated PDFBox into my project in order to generate image from a PDF page.
I made a unit test generating such image.
It works well in my dev environment.

However, when running the test in our gitlab, it is not able to load properly:

```
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1461)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1408)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:583)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader$1.run(JPEGImageReader.java:104)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader$1.run(JPEGImageReader.java:102)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.<clinit>(JPEGImageReader.java:101)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(JPEGImageReaderSpi.java:97)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(ImageReaderSpi.java:331)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:540)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:524)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.Filter.findImageReader(Filter.java:155)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.DCTFilter.decode(DCTFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInputStream.create(COSInputStream.java:80)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:179)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createInputStream(PDStream.java:241)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createInputStream(PDImageXObject.java:793)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.from8bit(SampledImageReader.java:517)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.getRGBImage(SampledImageReader.java:226)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:479)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:460)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawImage(PageDrawer.java:1059)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:67)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:933)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:515)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:489)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:275)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:347)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(PDFRenderer.java:240)
```

Anyone got an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: There are lots of google hits for "Library is already loaded in another ClassLoader".

Comment: What JDK does GitLab use when running the test? Is there a special class loader set up? This is the `com.sun...JPEGImageReader` bundled with the JDK, it should be able to load its native dependencies properly.